# Excel Files, C, and misery

Tags: c, excel, programming-languages, file, merge

Alright, so, I haven't programmed anything useful in ages - last time I did was a year ago and as you can imagine my knowledge of programming is seriously rusty. (last thing I 'programmed' was a ren'py game over the weekend. One can imagine the limited uses of this. The most advanced C program I wrote was a tic-tac-toe game a year ago. So yeah.)

Anyways, I've been given a job to write a program that takes two Excel files, both of which have a list of items, each associated with an ID. I need to write a program to search both files for IDs and if the IDs match, the program will need to create a new file with the matched IDs and items. This is insanely beyond my limited C capabilities.

If anyone could help, I would seriously appreciate it.

(also, if this is not possible with C, I'll do my best to work with any other languages)

Comment: If the files are CSV files, my FOSS tool CSVfix at http://code.google.com/p/csvfix/ will do exactly what you want with no programming.

Comment: C isn't a practical language to use for everything above systems programming. If scripting and game dev are your main areas of interest, you'd be better off with a different language.

Comment: Is it a xlsx or xls file (xlsx is xml data, xls is binary data) ?

Comment: It is surely possible with C. It has been years since I've used C myself, so I am not going to take a stab at how to do it. However, I will say that C wouldn't be my go-to language of choice with this problem. I'd look at a higher level language with better type safety and built-in memory management/garbage collection. Something like C#, VB.NET, or Java would be my choice.

Comment: Why don't you do this directly in Excel?  Doesn't sound like external tools are necessary.  A [Google search for "excel inner join"](http://www.google.com/search?q=excel+inner+join) will probably help.

Comment: @Akarshi in that case, use excel COM objects (if you really need a C program).

Comment: It doesn't necessarily have to be C - it's just that C is the only programming language that I am familiar with.

Comment: @Julio suggesting one programs COM objects in C is just plain silly.

Comment: @Akarshi Ok! So forget C and use C#. You will find lots of useful tools to handle an Excel file.

Comment: can you give a specific example of the data? This could probably be hammered out in perl in 5 minutes. Perl has capable libraries for reading excel files.

Answer (score 3):

Export the two files to .csv format and write a script to process the two files.  For example, in PHP, you have built in csv read/write capabilities.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with [VBA and create a Macro](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814737.aspx#odc_Office14_ta_GettingStartedWithVBAInExcel2010_MacrosAndTheVisualBasicEditor) in one of the files which iterates over the cells in your column in file 1 and compares them to cells in file 2 and writes them to a new .xls file if they match.

Dana points out that the [VLOOKUP function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx) will do this quite easily.

Comment: You can do this with the `VLOOKUP()` function as well.

Answer (score 1):

1. Install [GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/)
2. Output the excel files as text (csv for example)
3. *`sort` each file with the `-u` option to remove duplicates if needed*
4. mix and `sort` the 2 files
5. count unique IDs with `uniq -c`
6. filter out lines with a value of 1 for the count with `grep`
7. remove the count leaving the ID and whatever else you need with `cut`

Answer (score 1):

If you know Java then you can use Apache POI for your project. You can use the examples given on the Apache POI website to accomplish your task.

Apache POI Excel Documentation: http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely have to do this on xls/xlsx file from a process, you probably need a copy of Excel controlled by COM automation.  You can do this in BV/VBA/C#/C++ whatever, some easier than others.  Google for 'Excel automation'.

Rgds,
Martin

Answer (score 0):

Not C, but you may be able to cobble something together very quickly using [xlsperl](http://perl.jonallen.info/projects/xlsperl).

It has come in handy for me in the past.